# When building list recursively, how to use created elements of list at the head?

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to write a bootstrap algorithm in F# that takes a collection of inputs and creates a list of outputs. If I only need to use the previous element it is straightforward to use recursion :

```
let buildElement head previous =
    // do something to create new float 
    1.0

let buildList inputs =
    let rec bootstrap elements previous = 

        let addElement head tail =
            let newElement = buildElement head previous
            newElement :: bootstrap tail newElement   

        match inputs with
            | []    -> []
            | h::t  -> addElement h t
    bootstrap inputs 1.0
```

However, if I want to use the previously created elements (eg say I wanted to pass in an average of the new values as the previous value), how do I access them in the inner functions? Do I create a collection in the outer function and fill it up in the inner function? If so, do I need to make it mutable?

Comment: Note that your `buildList` function could just be defined as `List.scan buildElement 1.0 inputs` if you switch the arguments of `buildElement`.

Comment: That is a fair point. I am just trying to figure out the principle, this is just a cut-down version of the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to calculate the new value based on some information from the past values, you would essentially do the same thing as what you're doing now - instead of passing ingle last value in `previous`, the `previous` parameter could be a list of past values that you recalculate as you go.

I think it is difficult to give a better answer without knowing a specific example. However, say you wanted to calculate floating average - for that, you need the count and the sum of all previous values. You could encode that directly using recursion, or you can use `Seq.scan`:

```
[ 1.0 .. 100.0 ] 
|> Seq.scan (fun (count, sum) elem -> count + 1, sum + elem) (0, 0.0)
|> Seq.map (fun (count, sum) -> sum / float count)
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I think I have it now. I'll put the actual code up of fssnip when it's done, I think it will be something niec.

Answer (score 0):

In case of the average function you could pass the partial sum and the number of processed items around and use that calculate the average.

For a general solution, you can take the list of previous results as an argument, prepend the next result to it using `::` and reverse the whole thing when you're done. This has the added benefit of making your function tail-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

> if I want to use the previously created elements (eg say I wanted to pass in an average of the new values as the previous value), how do I access them in the inner functions?

This is a `fold` or `scan` (prefix fold). You're both mapping or collapsing a list into a new value, and accumulating a value that influences the result.